# Styling individual li id

Tags: html, css, nav

I have been trying to style the the link 'Devoted' in my nav menu, but am having no luck. Even going so far to try `!important`.

I'd simply like to change the text color.

```
{color: #DA9B4F}
```

This is the `li id` for the item.

```
<li id='nav-menu-item-219' class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom narrow">
```

The site in question is currently 242community.anchoragehosting.com.

Comment: The color of the text or the list item itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the page in Google Chrome, you can right click the 'Devoted' menu and click Inspect Element. You will then see that the `li` contains an `a` which contains a `span`. To change the text color, simply style the `span` element, like so:

```
#nav-menu-item-219 a span {
    color: #DA9B4F;
}
```

Comment: Had tried this, but just realized it was pulling from a different style sheet. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like that:

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

li#nav-menu-item-219 { 
    color: #DA9B4F;
}

li:before {
    content: "• ";
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-219">Bar</li>
    <li>Foo2</li>
</ul>
```